# How does one parent a channel to a category with a discord bot?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

Basically there is no errors in the output but at the same time it's not doing what I'm trying to achieve.

Ive been tinkering with the script for 5 hours straight mixing up line positioning and now I got it to where it gives me the promise (my initial issue) but I cant parent the channel.

I've tried discord.js server and site, youtube, 2 other sites i forgot the name of but i cant crack it.

```js
function setup(arguments, message){
    var server = message.guild;
    var name = message.author.username;
    let searchquery = arguments.join("")
    let cat = server.createChannel("Important", "category");
    async function Channelmaker(Sent, obj){
        try {
            let chan = await server.createChannel(Sent, "Text");
            //console.log(obj);

            return chan
        } catch(prom){
            var chan2 = await server.createChannel(Sent, "Text");
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                var chan2 = server.createChannel(Sent, "Text", parent = obj);
                resolve(chan2)
            });

        }

    }
    var holding
    var chan = Channelmaker("⚖️ rules ⚖️", cat).then(value => {
        console.log(value)
        holding = value
        value.parentID = cat
        chan.setParent(cat.Id)
    }).catch(error => {
        // s
    });
    console.log("holding")
    console.log(holding)
}
```

The category is not the parent of the `"⚖️ rules ⚖️"` channel that is created which is the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: What is the try/catch in your `Channelmaker` supposed to do?

Comment: make channels...

Comment: If it was obvious I wouldn't have to ask. The only operation in the try block that could throw is repeated in the catch block so that makes the catch pointless.

Comment: I legit read your comment wrong

Answer (score 1):

In [`Guild.createChannel()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=createChannel), use the `options` parameter including [ChannelData](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelData), like so:

```js
await server.createChannel(Sent, {
  // You can omit the 'type' property; it's 'text' by default.
  parent: obj
});
```